# logout when closing window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I have restful_authentication in my app. With that came a sessions controller. Everything has been working weel for me except one thing. When the window closes and is then reopened on the same machine, the apps state is saved including the logged in user. I require my app to log the user out when the browser window is closed. But I have no idea how to make it happen. Is there something that is causing it to save, or do I need to add something to kill it?

Here is the sessions controller:

```
# This controller handles the login/logout function of the site.  
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # render new.rhtml
  def new
  end

  def create
    logout_keeping_session!
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
    if user
      unless user.active?
        # ensures "deleted" users can't login
        user = nil
      end
    end
    if user
      # Protects against session fixation attacks, causes request forgery
      # protection if user resubmits an earlier form using back
      # button. Uncomment if you understand the tradeoffs.
      # reset_session
      self.current_user = user
      new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
      handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag
      redirect_back_or_default('/')
    else
      note_failed_signin
      @login       = params[:login]
      @remember_me = params[:remember_me]
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout_killing_session!
    redirect_back_or_default('/', :notice => "You have been logged out.")
  end

protected
  # Track failed login attempts
  def note_failed_signin
    flash.now[:alert] = "Couldn't log you in as '#{params[:login]}'"
    logger.warn "Failed login for '#{params[:login]}' from #{request.remote_ip} at #{Time.now.utc}"
  end
end
```

Here is the authenticatedSystem module (obviously unrelated material removed)

```
module AuthenticatedSystem
  protected
    # Returns true or false if the user is logged in.
    # Preloads @current_user with the user model if they're logged in.
    def logged_in?
      !!current_user
    end

    # Accesses the current user from the session.
    # Future calls avoid the database because nil is not equal to false.
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= (login_from_session || login_from_basic_auth || login_from_cookie) unless @current_user == false
    end

    # Store the given user id in the session.
    def current_user=(new_user)
      session[:user_id] = new_user ? new_user.id : nil
      @current_user = new_user || false
    end


    def authorized?(action = action_name, resource = nil)
      logged_in?
    end


    def login_required
      authorized? || access_denied
    end


    def access_denied
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          store_location
          redirect_to new_session_path
        end
        # format.any doesn't work in rails version < http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/8987
        # Add any other API formats here.  (Some browsers, notably IE6, send Accept: */* and trigger 
        # the 'format.any' block incorrectly. See http://bit.ly/ie6_borken or http://bit.ly/ie6_borken2
        # for a workaround.)
        format.any(:json, :xml) do
          request_http_basic_authentication 'Web Password'
        end
      end
    end

    # Store the URI of the current request in the session.
    #
    # We can return to this location by calling #redirect_back_or_default.
    def store_location
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end

    # Redirect to the URI stored by the most recent store_location call or
    # to the passed default.  Set an appropriately modified
    #   after_filter :store_location, :only => [:index, :new, :show, :edit]
    # for any controller you want to be bounce-backable.
    def redirect_back_or_default(default, options = {})
      redirect_to((session[:return_to] || default), options)
      session[:return_to] = nil
    end

    # Inclusion hook to make #current_user and #logged_in?
    # available as ActionView helper methods.
    def self.included(base)
      base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?, :authorized? if base.respond_to? :helper_method
    end

    #
    # Login
    #

    # Called from #current_user.  First attempt to login by the user id stored in the session.
    def login_from_session
      self.current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    # Called from #current_user.  Now, attempt to login by basic authentication information.
    def login_from_basic_auth
      authenticate_with_http_basic do |login, password|
        self.current_user = User.authenticate(login, password)
      end
    end

    #
    # Logout
    #

    # Called from #current_user.  Finaly, attempt to login by an expiring token in the cookie.
    # for the paranoid: we _should_ be storing user_token = hash(cookie_token, request IP)
    def login_from_cookie
      user = cookies[:auth_token] && User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:auth_token])
      if user && user.remember_token?
        self.current_user = user
        handle_remember_cookie! false # freshen cookie token (keeping date)
        self.current_user
      end
    end

    # This is ususally what you want; resetting the session willy-nilly wreaks
    # havoc with forgery protection, and is only strictly necessary on login.
    # However, **all session state variables should be unset here**.
    def logout_keeping_session!
      # Kill server-side auth cookie
      @current_user.forget_me if @current_user.is_a? User
#      @current_user = false     # not logged in, and don't do it for me
      kill_remember_cookie!     # Kill client-side auth cookie
      session[:user_id] = nil   # keeps the session but kill our variable
      # explicitly kill any other session variables you set
    end

    # The session should only be reset at the tail end of a form POST --
    # otherwise the request forgery protection fails. It's only really necessary
    # when you cross quarantine (logged-out to logged-in).
    def logout_killing_session!
      logout_keeping_session!
      reset_session
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your browser's (Firefox, in my case) start up preference are set to 'show my windows and tabs from last time'. It also happens when you 'save your tabs for the next time it starts' when closing the browser (all its windows). In these cases, the browser remembers the sesssion, i.e. it does not delete the session cookie as it would normally do.

Comment: yeah... that may be the case. I need a way to force it to delete that cookie on close.

Comment: you're on to something. On windows it's correct in IE8, opera, and safari, but not chrome. On OSX it's saving the login on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

When the user is re-opening their browser you are authenticating them from a cookie. Try removing `login_from_cookie` from

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= (login_from_session || login_from_basic_auth) unless @current_user == false
end
```

Comment: '    def login_from_cookie
      user = cookies[:auth_token] && User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:auth_token])
      if user && user.remember_token?
        self.current_user = user
        handle_remember_cookie! false # freshen cookie token (keeping date)
        self.current_user
      end
    end' <br /> that should only come into play if the "remember_me" option is selected, I have it disabled.

Comment: If that's true, then you need to do some serious digging into the authentication system. the only possible way to login when you open a new browser is a cookie.

Comment: turns out, this is working correctly on IE8 which unfortunately is my target browser. So I guess it's now really an urgent issue. (imagine that, something working right on IE!)

Comment: There's cookies flying all over that system. How do you go about putting an expiration time on them?

Comment: Try changing the session's secret in config/initializers/cookie_session_store (or config/initializers/secret_token)

Comment: Either way, run `rake secret` to generate a new secret and overwrite the secret... This will invalidate old signed cookies.